# OpenCV with C++ (building robotic arm)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.0

First of all I can say that I have some knowledge but obviously it is not enough for OpenCV.

Here is the thing: I am trying to do Object Detection with edge detection method. With this, I need to get X,Y coordinates and center position of the object. After that, the program needs to send this information to control board (Arduino) with serial port.

On the internet I found lots of examples and tutorials. But the problem starts here: lots of them are not working on my PC and I couldn't understand why. I am using Win10 and VS2015.

For example: after the installation I tried official OpenCV documentation of [Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier). When I tried to debug, it was not working.

Here is the error list of this code:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error (active)        no operator "=" matches these operands  deneme5 c:\Users\sertu\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\deneme5\deneme5.cpp   38   
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'IplImage *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  deneme5 c:\users\sertu\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\deneme5\deneme5.cpp   38   
Warning C4244   'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data    deneme5 c:\users\sertu\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\deneme5\deneme5.cpp   71   
Warning C4244   'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data    deneme5 c:\users\sertu\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\deneme5\deneme5.cpp   72   
Warning C4244   'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data    deneme5 c:\users\sertu\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\deneme5\deneme5.cpp   82
```

For OpenCV, I believe that I did everything. To install OpenCV, I followed YouTube video.

Weird thing is (at least it weird for me) that video has four examples. When I tried them, they were working :/

Can some body explain me why this code is not working which is from OpenCV documentation. It can be really simple and silly question maybe, but I messed up.

Comment: Please post the code *here*.

Comment: `IplImage` is legacy, part of the deprecated C API. Avoid that.